# Twilio integration

Tags: api, salesforce, twilio, voicemail

I am using twilio from salesforce (On a custom object) to call some numbers. Is there any way to send voicemails to those numbers without ringing there phone or with ring as least as possible . 
Will appreciate your help .
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "[What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)" and "[What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)". Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The voicemail of someone else's phone is not under control by Twilio. So you can't directly leave a voicemail without ringing them. You also cannot control the number of rings someone else's phone will make before going to voicemail.

Using Twilio, you could [make calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls) to the numbers and [play a message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) when they or their voicemail answers. This would either directly deliver the message to the user or record it on their voicemail.

**[edit]**:

After the discussion in comments below, here is an updated answer.

I'll give an overview of the system I think you need to build. I can't be more specific, because I have little details of your system or what you've tried.

I think you need to build in [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/twilio-js) to your Salesforce application. You can watch a video on how to [integrate Twilio Client with Salesforce](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2013/11/integrating-twilio-and-salesforce-to-streamline-your-crm.html).

You can use this to generate the calls to your customers and speak to them from within Salesforce.

To add to this, you also want to leave a message if you get a voicemail. You will need to do a few things to achieve this.

First, you will need to store the Call Sid of the call you made in the browser. You can get this from the [`parameters` attribute of the `Twilio.Connection`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/connection#parameters).

You will need to add a button to your interface that is active when you are on an active call. This button needs to hook up to an endpoint in your Salesforce app. The button should send the Call Sid you saved from your connection to the app.

Within the Salesforce app, you will need to build the endpoint for the above. This will receive the Call Sid as an argument. This Call Sid is the parent call and represents your connection to the call. We need to get the Child Call, which is the other end. We do this by calling on the [Calls resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list) passing the Call Sid as the [`ParentCallSid` parameter](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#list-get-filters). This will get you access to the child call.

You now need to [redirect the child call using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/change-call-state) to another endpoint that has the [TwiML to `<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) your recorded message for voicemail.

Then, when your user is on a call and it goes to voicemail, they should press the button in the interface. This will redirect the child call away and consequently hang up on the user in salesforce.

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: So you mean to say if any of our user is in call with customer he could drop a voicemails once the phone at other side ask for droping voicemail ? 
If yes so is there any specific way to redirect that call to a mp3 file whenever needed ?

Comment: It is possible, using [Twilio's Answering Machine detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/answering-machine-detection), to detect if a call is answered by voicemail then wait until the voicemail message is complete before leaving an automated message.

Comment: I don't need automatic voicemail system instead I am using button click to drop a voice mail when I listen beep for droping voice mail from the other end.
So can I redirect that current call to some prerecorded mp3 url so that get saved as voicemail.

Comment: Perhaps you can describe more clearly the entire application you would like to build by editing the question? That way I might be able to help. Otherwise I just keep guessing at the thing you want to achieve.

Comment: Sure below are the key things which we would like to build :  

1. We are using twilio from Salesforce CRM .  
2. Our users want to call some Phone Numbers via twilio.  

3. They want a feature to drop a prerecorded voicemail by clicking a button from salesforce whenever the phone at other end ask for dropping a voicemail.(Considering the beep sound).  

So is there any way to redirect the same call to our prerecorded mp3 files or anything similar which would get saved as voicemail to destination phone.

Comment: What do they want to do if the call doesn't go to voicemail?

Comment: So we are doing nothing in such cases .  We just want to drop our prerecorded voicemails if the machine at other end ask us to drop.

Comment: So, if a person answers the phone, you would hang up? I can't recommend this as a good way to treat your customers and their phones.

Comment: Sorry  I  missed to explain So our users will talk if the customer will pickup the phone otherwise at the time of beep sound we will drop a voicemail in the same call.

Comment: Hey  Philnash ,
Your suggestions worked and now I am able to send recordings in voicemails. Thanks for your help Cheers !!!